# Can I disable the transform attribute when a selected elements transform: translate3d = (0px, (x)px, 0px)

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

As you can see that I am moving the different layers through the use of javascript and the css transform attribute. I am looking for a way to select a certain layer and when it hits a specific number in the `transform: translate3d(0px, -1500px 0px)` You can see that I am `console.log()`'ing the current position of the attribute I want to freeze and stop parallaxing, I just have no clue in order to stop it when it reaches `transform: translate3d(0px, -1500px 0px)`

Any help would be much appreciated

```js
function castParallax() {
  window.addEventListener("scroll", function (event) {
    var top = this.pageYOffset;
    var layers = document.getElementsByClassName("parallax");
    var layer, speed, yPos;

    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
      layer = layers[i];
      speed = layer.getAttribute("data-speed");
      var yPos = -((top * speed) / 120);
      layer.setAttribute(
        "style",
        "transform: translate3d(0px, " + yPos + "px, 0px)"
      );
    }
  });
}

document.body.onload = castParallax();

window.addEventListener("scroll", function (event) {
  const freeze = document.querySelector("#keyart-2");
  let element = freeze.style.transform;

  console.log(element);

  // freeze parallax transform: translate3d(0px, -1500px, 0px);
});
```

```css
html {
    background-color: linear-gradient(345deg, rgba(248,187,199,1) 17%, rgba(3,137,182,0.6895133053221288) 77%);

}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
.keyart, .keyart_layer {
    height: 1000px;
}
#parallax {
    display: block;
    background-color: linear-gradient(345deg, rgba(248,187,199,1) 17%, rgba(3,137,182,0.6895133053221288) 77%);
}
.keyart {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-bottom: 240vh;
}
.keyart_layer {
    background-position: bottom center;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.keyart_layer.parallax {
    position: fixed;
    background-size: contain;
}
section {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top:200%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 2000px;
}
.test {
    background-color: #42600B !important;
    height: 300vh;
    color: white;
    z-index: 20;
    display: block;
    top: 2300px;
}
#keyart-0 {
    background-image: url('RDA-background.png');
    top: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 1;
    background-position: 100% 10%;
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100vw;
}
#keyart-1 {
    background-image: url('/RDA-mid2.png');
    z-index: 2;
    background-size: 85% 85% cover !important;
    background-position: 100%;
    height: 1500px;
    top: 1200px;
    right: 0;
}
#keyart-2 {
    background-image: url('/RDA-front.png');
    top: 300px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 3;
    height: 1600px;
    background-position: 100%;
    top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="keyart" id="parallax">
        <div class="logo" data-speed="100"><img src="/logo.png" alt="" ></div>
        <div class="keyart_layer parallax backbackground" id="keyart-2" data-speed="75"></div>
        <div class="keyart_layer parallax cloud" id="keyart-1" data-speed="300"></div>
        <div class="keyart_layer parallax background" id="keyart-0" data-speed="0"></div>
      </div>
      
    <section  class='test' data-speed="20">
      <h1 style="text-align:center;font-family:'Lucida Sans', sans-serif;font-size: 45px;">RADIOACTIVE PR</h1>
      <p style="text-align:center;font-family:'Lucida Sans',sans-serif;width:75%;margin:0 auto;">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, cum dicta nostrum, nulla, doloribus delectus sed perspiciatis reprehenderit soluta dolorem suscipit ullam.
      Nulla dolor optio dicta in molestias rem voluptatum libero iste, dolores, commodi quod nesciunt dolorem aliquam facilis eos voluptatem facere quis nam blanditiis? 
      Quo dolor ipsum possimus neque.</p>
    </section>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var yPos = Math.max(-1500, -((top * speed) / 120));`

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a treat! :)

Answer (score 0):

This has been covered on this thread...
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23378

but to summarize for you use this attribute on the button you click for the drop down : **data-display="static"** like shown below

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-display="static" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Left-aligned but right aligned when large screen
  </button>
```